# Compare String Arrays VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I have a 2 dimensional string array. In the string array are some strings and some integer numbers. I want to compare two positions of the array together.

Example:

```
If StringArray(1, 5) > StringArray(1, 6) Then
    MsgBox "Is first number is bigger"   
End if
```

My Debugger says:

```
StringArray(1,5) = 150
StringArray(1,6) = 3 
StringArray(1, 5) > StringArray(1, 6) = False
```

Does someone have an idea, why the Result is false? `StringArray(1, 5`) is definitely bigger. What could be the problem? Does it have something to do with the array type and how can i change that without creating a new integer array just for 2 Values?

Comment: The problem could be that 150 and 3 are being treated as strings. Therefor 3 > 1. So just cast them to Integer before comparing.

Comment: @PaulKaram : excellent.

Comment: @PaulKaram Thanks for the answer. For everybody who doesnt know that:
Val() function is for change a string Value to Integer

`Val(StringArray(1,5))`

Comment: @PatrickSchöpfer https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you stated, your array type is `String`.
When you're comparing `StringArray(1,5)` to `StringArray(1,6)`, you are actually comparing strings.

In your case, you are comparing `150` to `3` **as strings**. Hence the result is false, because "3" is > "1" and not vice verca.

In order to have it compare them as integers, you need to cast them to integers before. Like this:

```
If Val(StringArray(1, 5)) > Val(StringArray(1, 6))
```

There's other ways such as: [CInt](https://powerspreadsheets.com/vba-string-to-number/#2-Convert-String-to-Integer).

Comment: Thanks. Val() does the same as i know

Comment: @PatrickSchöpfer Yeah it does the same and more. I included three links of other ways as well.

Comment: `Convert.toInt32` and the "many other ways" link are non-VBA related. This is `.Net`

Comment: @Vityata Good point. I usually don't follow `VBA` so thing question must have been tagged with `VB.NET` before being edited. Anyways, I fixed that.